# Set a custom start date for week numbers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Outlook has the ability to show week numbers down the side of the calendar in monthly view, and on the mini-calendar:

[image]

In options, you can set the first week of the year, but only to the following three options:

[image]

This is all very nice, but at work our "year" starts on a different date to match up with accounting periods - it's currently week 37 rather than 45!

I'd like Outlook to be able to tell me which week it is at work, so is there any way I can set a custom date to be the first week of the year?

Comment: There's an an old KB support article for Office versions up to 2007 that explicitly says this can't be done. I'm not aware of any way to do it in 2010 either, so assume the article is still valid but just not updated to say it applies to 2010 too.

Comment: Really useful thing that MS dose not support. Not surprising at all.